# Trying to make plane lose speed when going up on steep angle and gain when going down in steep angle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So im trying to make my plane gain speed when decreasing altitude and lose it when going up.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float AmbientSpeed = 400.0f;

    public float RotationSpeed = 275.0f;

    private Rigidbody _rigidBody;
    bool IsInputEnabled = true;

    void Start()
    {
        _rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (IsInputEnabled)
        {
            // Slow down
            if (Input.GetKey("z"))
            {
                AmbientSpeed--;
                if (AmbientSpeed < 0)
                    AmbientSpeed = 0;
            }

            // Speed up
            if (Input.GetKey("x"))
            {
                AmbientSpeed++;
                if (AmbientSpeed > 400) 
                    AmbientSpeed = 400;
            }
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Quaternion AddRot = Quaternion.identity;
        float roll = 0;
        float pitch = 0;
        float yaw = 0;
        bool stall = false;

        // Getting pitch angle 
        var right = transform.right;
        right.y = 0;
        right *= Mathf.Sign(transform.up.y);
        var fwd = Vector3.Cross(right, Vector3.up).normalized;
        float pitch_rot = Vector3.Angle(fwd, transform.forward) * Mathf.Sign(transform.forward.y);

        // Engine stall
        if (IsInputEnabled)
        {
            Quaternion targetpos = new Quaternion(0.5f, AddRot.y, AddRot.z, AddRot.w);
            if (AmbientSpeed < 25)
            {
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetpos, 50 * Time.deltaTime);
            }

            if (stall == true && AmbientSpeed == 0 && AmbientSpeed < 100)
            {
                if (AmbientSpeed < 100)
                {
                    AmbientSpeed = AmbientSpeed + 1;
                }
                if (AmbientSpeed > 100)
                {
                    stall = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if (IsInputEnabled)
        {
            roll = Input.GetAxis("Roll") * (Time.fixedDeltaTime * RotationSpeed);
            pitch = Input.GetAxis("Pitch") * (Time.fixedDeltaTime * RotationSpeed);
            yaw = Input.GetAxis("Yaw") * (Time.fixedDeltaTime * RotationSpeed);
            AddRot.eulerAngles = new Vector3(-pitch, yaw, -roll);
            _rigidBody.rotation *= AddRot;
            Vector3 AddPos = Vector3.forward;
            AddPos = _rigidBody.rotation * AddPos;
            _rigidBody.velocity = AddPos * (Time.fixedDeltaTime * AmbientSpeed);

            if (Vector3.Dot(transform.up, Vector3.down) > 0)
            {
                _rigidBody.AddForce(0, 0, -10);
            }

            if (pitch_rot > 30)
            {
                AmbientSpeed = AmbientSpeed - 0.001f;

                if (AmbientSpeed < 0)
                {
                    AmbientSpeed = 0f;
                }
            }

            if (pitch_rot > 50 && AmbientSpeed < 200)
            {
                AmbientSpeed = AmbientSpeed - 10;
                if (AmbientSpeed < 0)
                {
                    AmbientSpeed = 0;
                    stall = true;
                }
                Debug.Log("Stalling");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code in C# The parts used for movement are in `FixedUpdate`. Just confused as how to get a smooth increase / decrease in `AmbientSpeed` when at steep angles. Any help appreciated. I'm quite new to Unity and c# so sorry if the code is a bit cluttered.

Here is the code with my attempt at comments not sure how useful they will be as alot of code is just taken from forum and the scripting page API document thing.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using Random = UnityEngine.Random;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Declare the max values
    public float AmbientSpeed = 400.0f;

    public float RotationSpeed = 275.0f;

    private Rigidbody _rigidBody;
    bool IsInputEnabled = true; //used in engine stall 

    void Start()
    {
        _rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (IsInputEnabled)
        {
            // Slow down the plane when Z is held
            if (Input.GetKey("z"))
            {
                AmbientSpeed--;
                if (AmbientSpeed < 0)  // Make sure min speed isnt broken
                    AmbientSpeed = 0;
            }

            // Speed up the plane when x is held
            if (Input.GetKey("x"))
            {
                AmbientSpeed++;
                if (AmbientSpeed > 400)  // Make sure max speed isnt broken
                    AmbientSpeed = 400;
            }
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Quaternion AddRot = Quaternion.identity; // Sets current Quaternion to AddRot variable 
        float roll = 0;
        float pitch = 0;
        float yaw = 0;
        bool stall = false;

        // Getting pitch angle 
        var right = transform.right;
        right.y = 0;
        right *= Mathf.Sign(transform.up.y);
        var fwd = Vector3.Cross(right, Vector3.up).normalized;
        float pitch_rot = Vector3.Angle(fwd, transform.forward) * Mathf.Sign(transform.forward.y);  // Complex math i don't understand

        // Engine stall
        if (IsInputEnabled)
        {
            Quaternion targetpos = new Quaternion(0.5f, AddRot.y, AddRot.z, AddRot.w); // Set target pos to a declining pitch
            if (AmbientSpeed < 25)
            {
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetpos, 50 * Time.deltaTime); // when engine gets below 25 speed then rotate towards the targetpos
            }

            if (stall == true && AmbientSpeed < 100) // if we are stalling
            {

                AmbientSpeed = AmbientSpeed + 1;   // Once stall is reached and plane is in decline the speed will increase due to steep decline

                if (AmbientSpeed > 100)
                {
                    stall = false;
                }
            }
        }

        if (IsInputEnabled)
        {
            roll = Input.GetAxis("Roll") * (Time.fixedDeltaTime * RotationSpeed);
            pitch = Input.GetAxis("Pitch") * (Time.fixedDeltaTime * RotationSpeed); // User input for Pitch/roll/yaw
            yaw = Input.GetAxis("Yaw") * (Time.fixedDeltaTime * RotationSpeed);
            AddRot.eulerAngles = new Vector3(-pitch, yaw, -roll); // Sets Addrot to currect pitch/yaw/roll
            _rigidBody.rotation *= AddRot;
            Vector3 AddPos = Vector3.forward;
            AddPos = _rigidBody.rotation * AddPos; // rotates rigid body to addrot
            _rigidBody.velocity = AddPos * (Time.fixedDeltaTime * AmbientSpeed);

            if (Vector3.Dot(transform.up, Vector3.down) > 0) // If upside down then fall
            {
                _rigidBody.AddForce(0, 0, -10);
            }

            if (pitch_rot > 30)                         // If pitch too far up lose speed
            {
                AmbientSpeed = AmbientSpeed - 0.001f;

                if (AmbientSpeed < 0)
                {
                    AmbientSpeed = 0f;
                }
            }

            if (pitch_rot > 50 && AmbientSpeed < 200)        // if go too far up pitch and lose too much speed you will stall
            {
                AmbientSpeed = AmbientSpeed - 10;
                if (AmbientSpeed < 0)
                {
                    AmbientSpeed = 0;
                    stall = true; // stall is true and input will be disabled
                }
                Debug.Log("Stalling");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use goto

Comment: care to refactor and lint a little bit? it hurts to look at it

Comment: i don't know what you mean sorry

Comment: will remove the goto

Comment: lint: There are lots of empty lines and wrong indentations, refactor: the whole code is written into one huge update method, there aren't enough comments to explain the logic and to highlight the exact line of interest. And thanks for removing that blasphemous goto!

Comment: I have class where i will be working on this at 2pm UK time will fix it and add comments for you then and upload it at around 2:40

Comment: I edited your code and made it more readable however there is a line which doesn't make sense: `if (stall == true && AmbientSpeed == 0 && AmbientSpeed < 100)`

Comment: In your code you set the speed so in terms of driving a car you dont use phyics to accelerate to 30, 40 , 70 you're just telling he car you're travelling at..which while this means it uses phyics for gravity, collisions etc, it cant take anything else into account, such as beuse you block speed you wouldnt gain any going down hill, nor would you slow going up a hill.

Comment: Bizhan it is so when the stall is true and speed is < 100 it should up speed to 100 overtime until 100 as it will pitch down. Anyway im in class now so can open visual studio and add comments and such

Comment: Bugfinder how can i make it accelerate instead of the way i do it? I thought this was acceleration but i guess not.